# SQLite в ngCordova. Почему кавычки влияют на результат запроса?

Tags: sqlite, ionic

Проект в ionic. Столкнулся с тем, что запросы:

```
$cordovaSQLite.execute(db, "SELECT * FROM t WHERE st = 'someText'", [])...
и
$cordovaSQLite.execute(db, 'SELECT * FROM t WHERE st = "someText"', [])...
```

работают по разному. В первом случае выдается ожидаемый ответ, т.е. строгое соответствие, а во втором, как будто запрос написан так:

```
"SELECT * FROM t WHERE st LIKE 'someText*'"
```

Кто нибудь может объяснить, почему так происходит?

UPD:
Благодарю Roman`а за подробное разъяснение! 
Если интересно, что такое prepared statements - http://habrahabr.ru/post/148446/

Comment: может быть, дело не столько в кавычках, сколько в содержимом `someText`?

Comment: В t.st хранились следующие значения: fileName, fileNa, fileName1, fileName2. Ни каких изысков =)

Comment: 1. вероятно, в вопросе должно быть не `'someText*'`, а `'someText%'`. 2. проверил в командной строке *sqlite*-ом (`sqlite3 /tmp/some.file`, `create table` и т.д.) ­— не воспроизводится. видимо, дело именно в этой самой *ngcordova* (впервые сегодня увидел это название). если разработчики принимают багрепорты — наверно, настало время их писать.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В SQL что-то в одинарных кавычках (например, `'foobar'`) - это текст, а что-то в двойных кавычках (например, `"baz"`) - идентификатор (вообще, зависит от БД).
SQLite, например, позволяет заключать текст в двойные кавычки для обратной совместимости, но это крайне не рекомендуется (см. https://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html).

Но я подозреваю, что т.к. у вас это angularjs, строка с запросом может проходить через несколько этапов экранирования/разэкранирования, что может её несколько портить и приводить к странным результатам (т.е. в базу можеть уйти не тот запрос, который вы хотите).

UPD:

Не знаю, влияет ли это на вашу ситуацию, но раз уж `$cordovaSQLite` поддерживает prepared statements, правильнее делать запрос так:

```
$cordovaSQLite.execute(db, "SELECT * FROM t WHERE st = ?", ["someText"])
```

Comment: Roman, благодарю Вас за разъяснения!
$cordovaSQLite как-то странно связывает / подставляет данные, поэтому пришлось для подстановки написать свою функцию.